# Adding ArcToolbox tool to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have been using a publicly available tool in ArcGIS called [SPreAD-GIS](http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~sereed/research/SPreAD-GIS.html). It is a series of python scripts that are "implemented as an ArcGIS toolbox" (with tbx file).

I am new to QGIS.

Is there a way to incorporate and use SPreAD-GIS in QGIS?

Answer (score 14):

Generally speaking, You cannot add an ArcGIS toolbox to QGIS, as it relies on Arcgis to work.

Most of the python scripts, actually call the standard ArcGIS Geoprocessing tools. Very Few Scripts are pure Python, or call other libraries.

Since there is no 1:1 correspondence between ArcGIS geoprocessing Tools and QGIS's pyqgis, you really can't expect the scripts to work without modification.

Coming to toolboxes. ArcGIS's .tbx files are binary files in a proprietary format, and cannot be read outside of ArcGIS.

Hence, generally speaking, you cannot add and use an ArcToolbox with QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

This would be a very expensive route to take but in theory an organisation could use ArcGIS for Server 10.1 to publish your ArcGIS toolbox tool(s) as OGC Web Processing Services (WPS) to be consumed by QGIS for which I think there is a WPS plug-in available.